# No puedo convertir implícitamente tipo 'void' a 'system.threading.thread'

Tags: c#

He puesto una función que incluirá mi *thread* del siguiente modo:

```
public static void Start()
{
    _thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Funciona");
            // Perform check or processing
            IntPtr address = GetModuleHandle(null);
            int dwOld;
            int o = 0;
            VirtualProtect(address, (IntPtr)4096, (int)0x40, out dwOld);
            ZeroMemory(address, (IntPtr)4096);
            VirtualProtect(address, (IntPtr)4096, (int)0x40, out o);
            VirtualFree(address, 0, FreeConsts.MEM_RELEASE);
            Console.WriteLine("Funciona");
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20000));
        }
    }).Start();
}
```

Pero cuando lo hago me muestra:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Thread' (CS0029) - C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\Desktop\Crypter - Definitif\Stub\Program.cs:70,27

¿A qué se debe esto y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3):

En la última línea llamas a `Start()` lo cual no devuelve ningun valor (`void`) y por lo tanto no puedes asignarlo a `_thread`.

Para solucionarlo simplemente llama a `.Start()` después de la asignación

```
public static void Start()
{
    _thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Funciona");
            // Perform check or processing
            IntPtr address = GetModuleHandle(null);
            int dwOld;
            int o = 0;
            VirtualProtect(address, (IntPtr)4096, (int)0x40, out dwOld);
            ZeroMemory(address, (IntPtr)4096);
            VirtualProtect(address, (IntPtr)4096, (int)0x40, out o);
            VirtualFree(address, 0, FreeConsts.MEM_RELEASE); 
            Console.WriteLine("Funciona");
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20000));
        }
    });
    _thread.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
Thread _thread = new Thread(() => //especificas el type
{
    _thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Funciona");
            // Perform check or processing 
            IntPtr address = GetModuleHandle(null);
            int dwOld; 
            int o = 0; 
            VirtualProtect(address, (IntPtr)4096, (int)0x40, out dwOld); 
            ZeroMemory(address, (IntPtr)4096);
            VirtualProtect(address, (IntPtr)4096, (int)0x40, out o);
            VirtualFree(address, 0, FreeConsts.MEM_RELEASE);
            Console.WriteLine("Funciona");
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20000));
        }
    });                      
    _thread.Start(); //Es necesario que identifiques el objeto
}
```